# Make SharePoint list dynamic?

Tags: sharepoint-list, powerbi

I have a Power BI dashboard connected to a SharePoint list. One of the columns in the SharePoint List is a "Today" column and automatically inputs the current date. The problem is that the "Today" column does not change day by day like it does in Excel. It remains as the date I inputted the list item but I want it to change every day to the current date.

This is very important in my project. Is this possible? Any help would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my question by finding this link: https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2017/12/08/use-microsoft-flow-to-create-a-today-column-for-use-in-sharepoint-list-calculations/

Answer (score 0):

There is no real simple solution to this. The only thing you can do is to move the logic to evaluate the field to the outside of the list.

I had a very odd support case once where a customer wrote a site workflow that updated the fields value every day. But they expanded the workflow so it updated 15 lists, then it ran into a timeout and was restarted...over and over again.

Is there a way you can move the math that depends on today to the outside of the list?

Answer (score 0):

you can't have a TODAY field in sharepoint, if the problem is power bi you will have to create a "today" calculated column inside power bi, sharepoint can't display a "today" date.

you can create it on the data view as =Today()
or create it on the query editor as DateTime.LocalNow()

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Today-Function-in-Column/td-p/85568

If you want to have a "today" field in sharepoint.. that's not going to be possible.